# How to print using only the color cartridge?

Tags: printing, settings, canon

My printer ran out of black ink, but the color cartridge still has a lot of ink. I want to print using only ink from the color cartridge. I used to be able to do this using advanced printer settings of the printer driver in Windows 7. I was wondering if and how it can be done using Ubuntu. I'm also new to Ubuntu,so I have no idea how to fiddle around with advanced settings.

My printer is a Canon iP2770 inkjet.

Comment: Regardless of system, you could convert your image to contain only colors. This online tool can do that: https://supertool.org/automatically-add-color-to-pdfs-to-print-without-black-ink/  (Or you could do this in Photoshop or similar)

Answer (score 7):

1. Open up the *Printers* utility.
2. Right click on your printer and select *Properties*.

   [image]
3. From the list on the left side, select *Printer Options*. Then scroll down to the *Printer Features Common* section and change the *Ink Set* option to *Color*.

   [image]
4. Hit *Apply*. The printer will now print using only the ink from the color cartridge.

Comment: :( My `Ink Set` only has `None` as an option.

Comment: The form is totally different on my PC there is no such setting.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Mac computer with an Epson printer and was trying to print a copied image using my color cartridges only since my black ink level was too low. Normally I would copy and paste and try to edit the image so that I could easily change the font color and boom it would automatically print in that color HOWEVER because this was a copied image, every time I clicked on it, it just allowed me to move the image etc but not change the preset black color. HOW FRUSTRATING. So using the LibreOffice app for Mac I pasted the image and did the following so that it would change the color.

There is a little paint drop looking icon on the top far right of the toolbar. I simply clicked that and a window popped up and it allows you to change the color of everything in the image. You can adjust the brightness and shading as well as the individual colors of red, green and blue.

Viola, within seconds I had my image color changed so it used my color cartridge only.

Not sure if this is useful to anyone else but thought I would throw it out there.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  While this could be valuable input, it would be more suited to a comment until the concept can be verified for Ubuntu.  You can test this on your own by downloading VirtualBox for Mac and installing Ubuntu as a VM.