# How to print using only color cartridge WHEN OUT OF BLACK INK?

Tags: printing, epson

My printer ran out of black ink, but the color cartridge still has a lot of ink. I want to print using only ink from the color cartridge. I used to be able to do this using advanced printer settings of the printer driver in Windows 7. I was wondering if and how it can be done using Ubuntu. I'm also new to Ubuntu,so I have no idea how to fiddle around with advanced settings.

My printer is a EPSON L210 inkjet.

Comment: See the properties on the printer (dupe using a canon: http://askubuntu.com/questions/113956/how-to-print-using-only-the-color-cartridge ).

Answer (score 1):

Open Printer utility, right click on your printer and select properties, select printer options in the left pane, scroll down printer features common in the right pane and select color option in the ink set and select apply. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't speak for your specific model, the issue is typically built into the printer so if you're out of ink in any cartridge, you cannot print at all until it's been replaced. No matter brand or model, I've never owned a printer that would allow printing if any cartridge was empty and nothing to do with the operating system or printer driver.